# ::Evernote::EDAM::NoteStore::NoteResultSpec is not defined

Tags: ruby, evernote

The API documentation provides a struct for a NoteResultSpec, which ostensibly allows one to include note content in an API request, but this does not appear to be available in the Ruby SDK.  I can get metadata using NotesMetadatResultSpec, but this does not include note content.

https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Struct_NoteResultSpec

Is there any way to get note content using the ruby SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NoteStore.getNote](https://dev.evernote.com/doc/reference/NoteStore.html#Fn_NoteStore_getNote) with `withContent` true to get note contents.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll try that.